# Result of expansion changes based on when I define a quantity

Tags: symbolic, series-expansion

I have code where I evaluate a series expansion symbolically. I want to do the same thing *without* explicitly specifying the point before the expansion. Naively, I think this should not change my result, but it does. I have attached the code below:

```
$Assumptions = {M > 0, a > 0, r > 0, a < M, ω > 0}; 
Δ[r_] := r^2 + a^2 - 2*M*r; 
f[r_] := Δ[r]/(r^2 + a^2); 
V = (KK^2 - λ)/(r^2 + a^2)^2 - G[r]^2 - f[r]*Derivative[1][G][r]; 
G[r_] := (r*Δ[r])/(r^2 + a^2)^2; 
KK = (r^2 + a^2)*ω - a*m; 
eqn = Simplify[f[r]^2*Derivative[2][R][r] + Derivative[1][f][r]*f[r]*Derivative[1][R][r] + V*R[r]];
```

I want to expand this equation around one of the roots of the function `Δ[r]` as done below. Note that `rplus` and `rminus` are roots of the (polynomial) function `Δ[r]`.

```
rplus = M + Sqrt[M^2 - a^2];
rminus = M - Sqrt[M^2 - a^2];
R[r_] := ((r - rplus)^AA*h[r]); 
eqn1 = Simplify[(eqn/(r - rplus)^AA)]; 

Clear[R]
ORDH = 3; 
h[r_] := Sum[hh[i]*(r - rplus)^i, {i, 0, ORDH}]; 
ruleH = {AA -> (I*(a*m - 2*M*(M + Sqrt[-a^2 + M^2])*ω))/(2*Sqrt[-a^2 + M^2])}; 
ss = Simplify[Chop[Series[eqn1 //. ruleH, {r, rplus, ORDH}]]]; 
eqsH = Table[SeriesCoefficient[ss, i] == 0, {i, 1, ORDH}]; 
yh = Table[hh[i], {i, 1, ORDH}]; 
Length[eqsH]
Length[yh]
seriesH = Simplify[Solve[eqsH, yh][[1]]]; 
seriesH = Union[seriesH, ruleH]; 
Clear[h]
```

If I define `rplus`,`rminus` before I take the expansion, then I get meaningful results. However if I expand about some arbitrary value say `r1` (and I set the right assumption taking `r1` > `r2` which I will later substitute for `rplus`,`rminus`), and take `r1 -> rplus` in the resulting symbolic series expansion, I do not get the same answers, and sometimes even get zero. I suspect this has to do with `rplus` being the root of the function `Δ[r]` and the function being directly defined in terms of that. But the equation itself is not zero at this point, so I don't see why the expansion should change just depending on where in the code I choose to define the point of expansion.

Comment: The symbol `D` is reserved in Mma for derivatives. Therefore, `D[r]` is an error. Use `d[r]` instead.

Comment: In the original program, the function is defined as \[Capital Delta][r]. I just wrote D here.

Comment: @newtothis It would be a good idea to change that D to something else that does not conflict with built ins. See also [How to copy code so it looks good here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB, I have used Raw Input Form as mentioned in the question you linked. I hope this is okay.

Comment: @newtothis Great, thank you! I changed `D[r]` to `Δ[r]` in the text of your post, since that's what I think you meant. Check to make sure that I didn't mess anything up!